# Does get_dummies() function change the dtype of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame column `['Cause']` with dtype as `object` having the below values :

`Cause
Water
Fire
Earthquake
Flood`

Now when I am using get_dummies() function on this column, I got 4 additional column as below with binary values:

`Water | Fire | Earthquake | Flood`

My query is , all these additional 4 columns has a data type as `uint8`.Do I need to convert it into `int64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on you, it still behaves like a integer...

So you can use it like any other integer, but also you should know there is a `str.get_dummies` which is default already `int64`:

```
>>> df['Cause'].str.get_dummies()
   Earthquake  Fire  Flood  Water
0           0     0      0      1
1           0     1      0      0
2           1     0      0      0
3           0     0      1      0
>>> df['Cause'].str.get_dummies().dtypes
Earthquake    int64
Fire          int64
Flood         int64
Water         int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by default if you don't mention dtype it will be converted to uint8.

You can do something like this

```
pd.get_dummies(..., dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I am using this code `New_df = pd.get_dummies(df['Cause'],dtype=int64)` and getting the error as 'name `int64' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert again. While converting it to `get_dummies()` you can define `dtype` :

```
pd.get_dummies(['Column_name'], dtype=np.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

`uint8` is the default data type that pandas forms the 'dummified columns' with.
You can always change it to different **dtype**.

But remember, that dtype will be assigned to **all the dummified columns**.
For example:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col1'], dtype='str')
```

would create dummified columns, all with the datatype **str**.