# In Pandas, what is the correct dtype for binary (dummy) variables?

Tags: python, pandas, binary-data, dummy-variable

In Pandas, what is the correct dtype for binary (dummy) variables?

There are obviously lots of dtypes in Pandas, some of which are:
`float64`, `int64`, `category`, or simply `object`. To me, these all seem like correct dtypes for binary (dummy) variables. Which one is the right answer?

If the correct dtype is `category`, I have a follow-up question which is basically I am unable to cast a column in pandas as `dtype='category'`, but we will cross that bridge when we get there.

Comment: What do you mean by "dummy"? That usually means something like a placeholder that isn't used for anything.

Comment: A dummy variable is one that takes the values 0 or 1 to indicate the absence or presence of some categorical effect that may be expected to shift the outcome. For example, if we were studying the relationship between gender and income, we could use a dummy variable to represent the gender of each individual in the study. The variable would take on a value of 1 for males and 0 for females. -Wikipedia

Comment: What is the default dtype generated by pandas? See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: int or bool. Category is reserved with more than two groups.

Comment: I would call that a flag variable or a boolean variable, not dummy.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Just wanted to make sure that this "int" variable is actually picked up by my linear regression as a binary variable instead of just some random integer.

Comment: @Barmar agreed theres honestly so many terms for the same thing, i get annoyed too. should be a master dictionary somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does get\_dummies() function change the dtype of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55333191/does-get-dummies-function-change-the-dtype-of-a-column)